# How can i get sheet names from excel file without using workbook?

Tags: java, excel, file, javafx, hssfworkbook

I need names for all sheet in excel file. I have checked all the answers to this question but they are using workbook.

I'm working on JavaFX application where I have created a File Explorer by Tree view. When I'm clicking on excel file or expanding excel file, this is taking too much time as each sheet contains thousands of rows and hundreds for columns.
I just want to show user only sheet name at starting and when a user double click on sheet then I'll get an actual sheet from workbook, Not at the time of expanding excel file because one excel file can have many sheets.

In short, I need to eliminate this code to get sheet names:-

```
public List<String> getWorkBookSheetsName(File file) {
    Workbook workbook = null;
    List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        if (file.getAbsolutePath().endsWith(".xls")) {
            workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fis);
        } else {
            workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < workbook.getNumberOfSheets(); i++) {
         String sheetName = workbookSelectedFile.getSheetName(i);
         names.add(sheetName);
    }

  return names;
}
```